# Lexical analysis in MRI Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, compiler-construction, lexer

I'm learning some compiler theory and practice at the moment.  Ruby is my every day language of choice, and so I went to look at its lexer and parse grammar.  Does ruby have a separate lexer?  If so, which file is it described in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ruby source there is the `parse.y` file which contains the grammar. I am relatively sure that ruby uses a separate lexer (like most LR parsers). Also it seems like the lexer is stateful:

```
enum lex_state_e {
EXPR_BEG,           /* ignore newline, +/- is a sign. */
EXPR_END,           /* newline significant, +/- is an operator. */
EXPR_ENDARG,        /* ditto, and unbound braces. */
EXPR_ARG,           /* newline significant, +/- is an operator. */
EXPR_CMDARG,        /* newline significant, +/- is an operator. */
EXPR_MID,           /* newline significant, +/- is an operator. */
EXPR_FNAME,         /* ignore newline, no reserved words. */
EXPR_DOT,           /* right after `.' or `::', no reserved words. */
EXPR_CLASS,         /* immediate after `class', no here document. */
EXPR_VALUE          /* alike EXPR_BEG but label is disallowed. */
};
```

I guess this necessary because a newline is ignored in some cases and in other cases it terminates expressions etc. Also 'class' is not always a keyword like e.g. in 'x.class'.

But i'm no expert.

EDIT: Looking deeper in the parse.y file the lexer is not completely separate from the parser:

```
superclass  : //[...]
    | '<'
        {
        lex_state = EXPR_BEG;
        }
```